# iOS 15.4.0 ShareSheet _activityImage is not supported for proxies to out-of-process activities

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios-sharesheet, ios-15.4

From iOS 15.4.0 we have the crash on Crashlytics but don't known how to reproduce and fix it. It is producing crash due to Apple default shareSheet. I hope someone can provide some insights to fix this.

Code I use to open shareSheet

```
func shareFiles(rootVC: UIViewController, items: [Any]) {
    
   let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    
   // This lines is for the popover you need to show in iPad
   activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = rootVC.view
   // This line remove the arrow of the popover to show in iPad
   activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
   activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2,
                                        y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height,
                                        width: 0, height: 0)
    
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
     rootVC.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of our applications was producing the exact same crash on production and We've made a workaround for the crash.

You can create a **CustomShareSheet** class that extends **UIActivityViewController** and this class will dismiss the CustomShareSheetController when the application will resign from its active state, thus the crash won't occur anymore.

```
class CustomShareSheet: UIActivityViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        debugPrint("CustomShareSheet \(#function)")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillResignActive(notification:)), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc private func applicationWillResignActive(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
        debugPrint("\(#function) || dismissed")
    }
}
```

===========================

```
class Helper {

    class func shareFiles(rootVC: UIViewController, items: [Any]) {
         debugPrint("\(#function) || itemCount: \(items.count)")

        let customShareSheet = CustomShareSheet(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil) // Uses of CustomShareSheet
        // This lines is for the popover you need to show in iPad
        customShareSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = rootVC.view
        // This line remove the arrow of the popover to show in iPad
        customShareSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .down
        customShareSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2,
                                                                                  y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height,
                                                                                  width: 0, height: 0)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            rootVC.present(customShareSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

===========================

```
var _items = [Any]()
Helper.shareFiles(rootVC: yourCurrentViewController, items: _items)
```

Comment: can't we dismiss it without creating customVC?

Comment: Did you find a way to reproduce it?