# IOS crash - ShareSheet _UIShareServiceProxyRaiseInvocationUnsupportedForInstance

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ios-sharesheet

in my app there is page which you can download a pdf report and i show the pdf report report with **UIDocumentInteractionController** as below

```
            let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            
            viewer.delegate = self

            viewer.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

It works fine but there is a problem with **Sharing the pdf report in UIDocumentInteractionController**

Last six month i'm getting this crash on firebase **Attempt to invoke -_activityImage on <_UIShareServiceActivityProxy_Share: 0x286935d40>, which is not supported for proxies to out-of-process activities.**

**Also i got this crash twice when i scrolled the suggested share users rarely**

Here is the stack trace

```
\`# Crashlytics - Stack trace

# Application: com.myapp.app

# Platform: apple

# Version: 5.9.4 (1)

# Issue: a978e4ca335f2455402e3836dd0b3324

# Session: cbc5d94f1c05494384925958847f4dec_DNE_0_v2

# Date: Wed Nov 16 2022 19:55:09 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)\`

\`Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x9e88 \__exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x178d8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0xf9c58 \__CFDictionaryCreateGeneric
3  ShareSheet                     0x6747c \_UIShareServiceProxyRaiseInvocationUnsupportedForInstance
4  ShareSheet                     0x673f4 -\[\_UIShareServiceActivityProxy methodSignatureForSelector:\]
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1fad4 ___forwarding___
6  CoreFoundation                 0x88350 \_CF_forwarding_prep_0
7  SharingUI                      0x2ddf0 -\[SFUIActivityImageProvider \_fetchImageForActivity:contentSizeCategory:imageSymbolConfiguration:\]
8  SharingUI                      0x2d9b8 -\[SFUIActivityImageProvider performImageRequest:\]
9  SharingUI                      0x12b1c \__42-\[SFUIImageProvider scheduleImageRequest:\]\_block_invoke
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x24b4 \_dispatch_call_block_and_release
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc \_dispatch_client_callout
12 libdispatch.dylib              0xb694 \_dispatch_lane_serial_drain
13 libdispatch.dylib              0xc214 \_dispatch_lane_invoke
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x16e10 \_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 \_pthread_wqthread
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread

com.apple.uikit.datasource.diffing
0  QuartzCore                     0x79458 -\[CALayerArray count\] + 12
1  UIKitCore                      0x8488c -\[UIView(Hierarchy) bringSubviewToFront:\] + 72
2  UIKitCore                      0x84290 -\[\_UICollectionViewOrthogonalScrollerSectionController adjustElementHierarchyOrderingForOrthogonalElementIfNeeded:layoutAttributes:\] + 204
3  UIKitCore                      0x2b178 -\[UICollectionView \_addControlledSubview:atZIndex:forced:initialAttributes:\] + 1032
4  UIKitCore                      0x6fb74c -\[UICollectionView \_updateLayoutAttributesForExistingVisibleViewsFadingForBoundsChange:\] + 1272
5  UIKitCore                      0x2a0fc -\[UICollectionView \_updateVisibleCellsNow:\] + 1632
6  UIKitCore                      0x2a2d8 -\[UICollectionView \_updateVisibleCellsNow:\] + 2108
7  UIKitCore                      0x299ac -\[UICollectionView layoutSubviews\] + 304
8  ShareSheet                     0x67f20 -\[\_UIActivityContentCollectionView layoutSubviews\] + 132
9  UIKitCore                      0x5020 -\[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:\] + 1980
10 QuartzCore                     0x99ec CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction\*) + 500
11 UIKitCore                      0xd21dc -\[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded\] + 292
12 UIKitCore                      0x1a04d0 -\[UICollectionView reloadData\] + 2184
13 UIKitCore                      0x245844 -\[UICollectionView \_performInternalBatchUpdates:\] + 56
14 UIKitCore                      0x2441e8 -\[UICollectionView \_performDiffableUpdate:\] + 88
15 UIKitCore                      0x245a1c -\[\_UIDiffableDataSourceViewUpdater \_reloadData\] + 136
16 UIKitCore                      0x242668 \__56-\[\__UIDiffableDataSource reloadFromSnapshot:completion:\]\_block_invoke + 164
17 UIKitCore                      0x4aabbc \__56-\[\__UIDiffableDataSource reloadFromSnapshot:completion:\]\_block_invoke_2 + 52
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc \_dispatch_client_callout + 20
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x13574 \_dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
20 UIKitCore                      0x239524 -\[\__UIDiffableDataSource reloadFromSnapshot:completion:\] + 556
21 UIKitCore                      0x239250 -\[UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource applySnapshotUsingReloadData:completion:\] + 72
22 ShareSheet                     0x3d0dc -\[UIActivityContentViewController reloadContent\] + 64
23 ShareSheet                     0x529dc -\[SHSheetPresenter \_willEnterForeground:\] + 64
24 CoreFoundation                 0x37404 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 148
25 CoreFoundation                 0xde474 \___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 88
26 CoreFoundation                 0xc1724 \_CFXRegistrationPost + 440
27 CoreFoundation                 0x4ba08 \_CFXNotificationPost + 704
28 Foundation                     0x5cffc -\[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:\] + 92
29 UIKitCore                      0x1a4cf0 -\[UIApplication \_sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks\] + 224
30 UIKitCore                      0x1a482c \__101-\[\_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer \_evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:\]\_block_invoke_2 + 1272
31 UIKitCore                      0x9e600 \_UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 108
32 UIKitCore                      0x3e0918 \__101-\[\_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer \_evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:\]\_block_invoke + 216
33 UIKitCore                      0x290fa4 -\[\_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer \_performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:\] + 220
34 UIKitCore                      0x290dcc -\[\_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer \_evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:\] + 620
35 UIKitCore                      0x29097c -\[\_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:\] + 252
36 UIKitCore                      0x290848 \__186-\[\_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction \_performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:\]\_block_invoke + 148
37 UIKitCore                      0x972fa8 +\[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:\] + 736
38 UIKitCore                      0xa0bf98 \_UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224
39 UIKitCore                      0x13c958 -\[\_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction \_performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:\] + 316
40 UIKitCore                      0x5af7a8 \__64-\[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:\]\_block_invoke.214 + 556
41 UIKitCore                      0x20f0b8 -\[UIScene \_emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:\] + 216
42 UIKitCore                      0x20ef28 -\[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:\] + 244
43 UIKitCore                      0x20ed68 -\[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:\] + 336
44 FrontBoardServices             0x3cdc -\[FBSScene updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:\] + 420
45 FrontBoardServices             0x3b18 \__94-\[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient \_queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:\]\_block_invoke_2 + 144
46 FrontBoardServices             0x7294 -\[FBSWorkspace \_calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:\] + 168
47 FrontBoardServices             0x71b0 \__94-\[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient \_queue_updateScene:withSettings:diff:transitionContext:completion:\]\_block_invoke + 340
48 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc \_dispatch_client_callout + 20
49 libdispatch.dylib              0x7a5c \_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
50 FrontBoardServices             0x113b0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
51 FrontBoardServices             0x10f4c -\[FBSSerialQueue \_targetQueue_performNextIfPossible\] + 220
52 FrontBoardServices             0x1372c -\[FBSSerialQueue \_performNextFromRunLoopSource\] + 28
53 CoreFoundation                 0xd5f54 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
54 CoreFoundation                 0xe232c \__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
55 CoreFoundation                 0x66270 \__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
56 CoreFoundation                 0x7bba8 \__CFRunLoopRun + 836
57 CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
58 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
59 UIKitCore                      0x3a23d0 -\[UIApplication \_run\] + 888
60 UIKitCore                      0x3a2034 UIApplicationMain + 340
61 fizbot                         0xa9dc main + 47 (AppDelegate.swift:47)
62 ???                            0x1f0e04960 (Missing)

GC Timer thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x141c \__psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x806c \_pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xcb68 std::\__1::condition_variable::\__do_timed_wait(std::\__1::unique_lock\<std::\__1::mutex\>&, std::\__1::chrono::time_point\<std::\__1::chrono::system_clock, std::\__1::chrono::duration\<long long, std::\__1::ratio\<1l, 1000000000l\> \> \>) + 100
3  Bifrost                        0x3cba1c void kotlin::RepeatedTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::Run\<kotlin::gc::internal::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer(kotlin::gc::GCSchedulerConfig&, std::\__1::function\<void ()\>)::'lambda'()\>(kotlin::gc::internal::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer(kotlin::gc::GCSchedulerConfig&, std::\__1::function\<void ()\>)::'lambda'()&&) + 556
4  Bifrost                        0x3cc0d4 void\* std::\__1::\__thread_proxy\<std::\__1::tuple\<std::\__1::unique_ptr\<std::\__1::\__thread_struct, std::\__1::default_delete\<std::\__1::\__thread_struct\> \>, void (*)(kotlin::ScopedThread::attributes, void (kotlin::RepeatedTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::*&&)(kotlin::gc::internal::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer(kotlin::gc::GCSchedulerConfig&, std::\__1::function\<void ()\>)::'lambda'()&&) noexcept, kotlin::RepeatedTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>*&&, kotlin::gc::internal::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer(kotlin::gc::GCSchedulerConfig&, std::\__1::function\<void ()\>)::'lambda'()&&), kotlin::ScopedThread::attributes, void (kotlin::RepeatedTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::*)(kotlin::gc::internal::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer(kotlin::gc::GCSchedulerConfig&, std::\__1::function\<void ()\>)::'lambda'()&&) noexcept, kotlin::RepeatedTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>*, kotlin::gc::internal::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer\<kotlin::steady_clock\>::GCSchedulerDataWithTimer(kotlin::gc::GCSchedulerConfig&, std::\__1::function\<void ()\>)::'lambda'()\> \>(void*) + 244
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

GC thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x141c \__psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x806c \_pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xcacc std::\__1::condition_variable::wait(std::\__1::unique_lock\<std::\__1::mutex\>&) + 28
3  Bifrost                        0x3c1e6c std::\__1::invoke_result\<kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep(kotlin::mm::ObjectFactory\<kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep\>&, kotlin::gc::GCScheduler&)::$\_2\>::type kotlin::ScopedThread::Run\<kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep(kotlin::mm::ObjectFactory\<kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep\>&, kotlin::gc::GCScheduler&)::$\_2\>(kotlin::ScopedThread::attributes, kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep(kotlin::mm::ObjectFactory\<kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep\>&, kotlin::gc::GCScheduler&)::$\_2&&) + 332
4  Bifrost                        0x3c1fdc void\* std::\__1::\__thread_proxy\<std::\__1::tuple\<std::\__1::unique_ptr\<std::\__1::\__thread_struct, std::\__1::default_delete\<std::\__1::\__thread_struct\> \>, void (*)(kotlin::ScopedThread::attributes, kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep(kotlin::mm::ObjectFactory\<kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep\>&, kotlin::gc::GCScheduler&)::$\_2&&), kotlin::ScopedThread::attributes, kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep(kotlin::mm::ObjectFactory\<kotlin::gc::ConcurrentMarkAndSweep\>&, kotlin::gc::GCScheduler&)::$\_2\> \>(void*) + 220
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xb48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x108c mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7aaf0 \__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x7bd34 \__CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7  Foundation                     0x42334 -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:\] + 212
8  Foundation                     0x4221c -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:\] + 64
9  UIKitCore                      0x4d733c -\[UIEventFetcher threadMain\] + 436
10 Foundation                     0x5b808 __NSThread__start__ + 716
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xb48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x108c mach_msg + 24
4  fizbot                         0x14eb56c FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 192 (FIRCLSMachException.c:192)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xb48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x108c mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7aaf0 \__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x7bd34 \__CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7  CFNetwork                      0x2565a8 \_CFURLStorageSessionDisableCache + 61088
8  Foundation                     0x5b808 __NSThread__start__ + 716
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

GC finalizer processor
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x141c \__psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x806c \_pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0xcacc std::\__1::condition_variable::wait(std::\__1::unique_lock\<std::\__1::mutex\>&) + 28
3  Bifrost                        0x3c99a0 std::\__1::invoke_result\<kotlin::gc::FinalizerProcessor::StartFinalizerThreadIfNone()::$\_0\>::type kotlin::ScopedThread::Run\<kotlin::gc::FinalizerProcessor::StartFinalizerThreadIfNone()::$\_0\>(kotlin::ScopedThread::attributes, kotlin::gc::FinalizerProcessor::StartFinalizerThreadIfNone()::$\_0&&) + 508
4  Bifrost                        0x3ca050 void\* std::\__1::\__thread_proxy\<std::\__1::tuple\<std::\__1::unique_ptr\<std::\__1::\__thread_struct, std::\__1::default_delete\<std::\__1::\__thread_struct\> \>, void (*)(kotlin::ScopedThread::attributes, kotlin::gc::FinalizerProcessor::StartFinalizerThreadIfNone()::$\_0&&), kotlin::ScopedThread::attributes, kotlin::gc::FinalizerProcessor::StartFinalizerThreadIfNone()::$\_0\> \>(void*) + 220
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x141c \__psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x806c \_pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2  Bifrost                        0x400030 Worker::waitForQueueLocked(long long, long long\*) + 484
3  Bifrost                        0x3ff3c8 Worker::processQueueElement(bool) + 420
4  Bifrost                        0x3ff1b0 (anonymous namespace)::workerRoutine(void\*) + 100
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x141c \__psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x806c \_pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2  Bifrost                        0x400030 Worker::waitForQueueLocked(long long, long long\*) + 484
3  Bifrost                        0x3ff3c8 Worker::processQueueElement(bool) + 420
4  Bifrost                        0x3ff1b0 (anonymous namespace)::workerRoutine(void\*) + 100
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xb48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x108c mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7aaf0 \__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x7bd34 \__CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7  Foundation                     0x42334 -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:\] + 212
8  GoogleMaps                     0x2bf3f8 -\[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main\] + 184
9  Foundation                     0x5b808 __NSThread__start__ + 716
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xb48 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x13248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x108c mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7aaf0 \__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x7bd34 \__CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7  Foundation                     0x42334 -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:\] + 212
8  GoogleMaps                     0x2bf3f8 -\[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main\] + 184
9  Foundation                     0x5b808 __NSThread__start__ + 716
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x16cc \_pthread_start + 148
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xba4 thread_start + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb90 start_wqthread + 254

com.apple.network.connections
0  Network                        0x2bf28c nw_flow_service_reads + 676
1  Network                        0x2e9128 nw_flow_disconnected + 1940
2  Network                        0x2e3924 nw_flow_passthrough_disconnected + 144
3  libusrtcp.dylib                0x1d1f8 \____nw_protocol_tcp_disconnect_block_invoke + 344
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x24b4 \_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc \_dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0xd620 \_dispatch_workloop_invoke + 2076
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x16e10 \_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 \_pthread_wqthread + 288
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb90 start_wqthread + 254

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb90 start_wqthread + 254

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb90 start_wqthread + 254

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb90 start_wqthread + 254

Crashed: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  fizbot                         0x14dd728 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 393 (FIRCLSProcess.c:393)
1  fizbot                         0x14ddb08 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 424 (FIRCLSProcess.c:424)
2  fizbot                         0x14eafb4 FIRCLSHandler + 34 (FIRCLSHandler.m:34)
3  fizbot                         0x14eae08 \__FIRCLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 232 (FIRCLSException.mm:232)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc \_dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x13574 \_dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
6  fizbot                         0x14e9e14 FIRCLSExceptionRecord + 234 (FIRCLSException.mm:234)
7  fizbot                         0x14ea928 FIRCLSExceptionRecordNSException + 126 (FIRCLSException.mm:126)
8  fizbot                         0x14e9a6c FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 398 (FIRCLSException.mm:398)
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x10f28 std::\__terminate(void (\*)()) + 20
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x10ec4 std::terminate() + 56
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x33bec objc_terminate + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3ff0 \_dispatch_client_callout + 40
13 libdispatch.dylib              0xb694 \_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
14 libdispatch.dylib              0xc214 \_dispatch_lane_invoke + 436
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x16e10 \_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 \_pthread_wqthread + 288
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread + 8

CCTLogWriter
0  libicucore.A.dylib             0x249890 ztrans_getDynamicClassID + 7974373520
1  libsystem_c.dylib              0x7508 bsearch + 68
2  libicucore.A.dylib             0x58c44 ualoc_getAppleParent + 1312
3  libicucore.A.dylib             0x593c0 ualoc_localizationsToUse + 512
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2f600 \_CFBundleCreateMutableArrayOfFallbackLanguages + 324
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2f188 \_CFBundleCopyPreferredLanguagesInList + 496
6  CoreFoundation                 0x16ad4 \_CFBundleCopyLocalizationsForPreferences + 76
7  CoreFoundation                 0xbf2d0 CFBundleCopyPreferredLocalizationsFromArray + 84
8  Foundation                     0x78184 +\[NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray:\] + 24
9  GoogleMapsBase                 0x350ac +\[GMSx_CCTClientInfoMaker currentLanguageCode\] + 60
10 GoogleMapsBase                 0x3560c -\[GMSx_CCTClientInfoMaker makeClientInfo:\] + 176
11 GoogleMapsBase                 0x30a64 -\[GMSx_CCTLogWriter writeLogInternal:pseudonymousID:logDirectory:clock:logTransformers:includeAccessibilityInfo:flags:\] + 1268
12 GoogleMapsBase                 0x3025c \__111-\[GMSx_CCTLogWriter writeLog:pseudonymousID:logDirectory:clock:logTransformers:includeAccessibilityInfo:flags:\]\_block_invoke + 56
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x24b4 \_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc \_dispatch_client_callout + 20
15 libdispatch.dylib              0xb694 \_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
16 libdispatch.dylib              0xc214 \_dispatch_lane_invoke + 436
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x16e10 \_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 \_pthread_wqthread + 288
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb90 start_wqthread + 254
```

I found a solution in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421441/ios-15-4-0-sharesheet-activityimage-is-not-supported-for-proxies-to-out-of-proc](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

but the problem is that i'm not manage the share button in UIDocumentInteractionController, the share button coming with default option and i needed it

Any idea to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting it too now. BTW - the link should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421441 - your is not working.